# How to add current time to a string concisely in C++?

Tags: c++, string, time

I'd like to add a timestamp to the filename in this part of my code:

```
takeScreenshot( "screenshot.png" );
```

But all ways of doing  this that I've found seem unnecessarily long and complicated. E.g. creating a new string, loading a time struct, converting an element of the time struct to a char array and appending it to the string.

Is there a short way to accomplish this? Most other languages would have some simple solution like:

```
takeScreenshot( sprintf( "screenshot-%d.png", time() ) );
```

Is there one in C++? The time format doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Concatenating a string *is* long and complicated, under the hood.

A nice way is to use `std::stringstream` which overloads `<<` for concatenation:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "screenshot-" << time() << ".png";
std::string s = ss.str();
```

and format `time()` to personal taste.

Comment: dont forget to add "sstream.h" header file..!

Answer (score -1):

You can use stringstream or just use + operator between strings:

```
takeScreenshot("screenshot-" + time() + ".png");
```

Comment: `"this is not a std::string and it cannot be added"`

Comment: you can also try boost::lexical_cast<std::string>